# how to use an instance defined in another class

Tags: python, class

I have 2 classes. I need to create an instance of Class1 in Class2, and use its method (also in Class2)

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, name, num):
        self.sum = sum


class Class2:
    name_list = []
    def add(self, name, num):
        'a method that adds an instance to Class1 and uses it here'
        something = Class1(name, num)
        name_list.append(something.name)

    def get_sum(self):
        sum = 0
        for i in Class1.lst:
            sum += i.sum
        return sum
```

Can I name the variable 'something' the same as the parameter 'name' given? so that I would be able to use the name_list as the instances names?
(I know I can just make a list of sums, but I need more methods that use the other class methods)
i

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please consider clarifying. Are you asking if you can name a variable `something`? Yes, you can. It's a poor choice of variable name, though. Note that your Class1 objects do not have `name` or `lst` attributes so your code won't work as currently written.

Comment: Avoid using `sum` as a variable name, as it's a built-in function. As for the name `something`, I wouldn't worry too much. If you're relying on what *you* name variables, it can make your code fragile

Comment: It's not what I meant. I want to replace 'something' with the value of 'name' .    and @ago-  I wrote it only as an example because my code is too long. Of course I didn't name anything as 'sum'. I just tried to make it clear.

Comment: Please [edit] your question an clarify what you're asking in _it_, not just down here in the comments. Also, how are going to reference `something` if you don't know what it's going to be in advance?

Comment: Hope it's clearer now I edited it

Answer (score 0):

It’s in the class, so will be in the instances of class 2. You’ll be not able to use it without the instance name